# Python: In numpy, how do I slice a column from an array without needing reshape?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to slice a column, but this gives me a one dimensional array. i.e.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b = a[1,:]


b.shape
# (3,)
```

But I want it to be 2 dimensional, i.e. (3,1)

Is there a way to do this without reshaping?

Comment: So in your case, `a[1, :, np.newaxis]`.

Comment: Why do you want it to be (3,1)?  Wouldn't (1,3) make more sense when selecting a row?  like `a[[1],:]`.  Reshaping gives you more control without costing anything but a bit of typing.